# MDI Designer View is showing HTML, instead of the form design

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2005, windows-forms-designer

I am not sure what is happened and have been searching for fixes all night. When I double click on the mdi form (or right click and select "View Designer") what appears, instead of the form designer view, is html. When attempting to debug, Visual Studio shows an error being thrown when attempting to create and instance of the form. The inner exception/stack trace is show below.

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled   Message="An error
>   occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. 
>   The error is: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"   Source="Blah"   StackTrace:
>          at Blah.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create_*Instance*_[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
>          at Blah.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_mdiBlah()
>          at Blah.mdiBlah.Main() in C:\Users\Home\Desktop\ClientSoftware\ClientSoftware\mdiBlah.Designer.vb:line
>   1
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
>          at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
>          at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
>          at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

A few common fixes for this issue is:

1. Check and make sure the class name in the code behind is the same as
   the class name in the designer code. Check.
2. Make sure that all references the project uses are included. Check.
3. A few other things that I, unfortunately, can not remember at this time.

I know this could be a fairly open-ended error. But I really need some direction on this, and hopefully it will serve also as a guide for someone else in the future.

Comment: You are using an ActiveX control on your form that is no longer properly registered.  Rerun its installer.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate a little more. This is actually something for a client that I have inherited. I have honestly never messed with ActiveX controls.

Comment: Hans, if you would, make your comment an answer as well as how you knew from the above stack trace that the issue was an ActiveX Control not being registered. This way I can accept the answer and maybe this will help others in the future. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via @Hans Passant, the answer is: You are using an ActiveX control on your form that is no longer properly registered. Rerun its installer. Thanks Hans